# Out of fuel, no missiles and encountered, what can I do?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

This is a very strange situation (see attached..), Is there anything one can do to run / defend / fight back?

[image]

Comment: Without a beam weapon, I think your only option at that point is to start over.

Comment: I know, after considering the situation I've noticed that 'Enemy FTL Charging', so they are on the run, but the killed me before they escaped :-(

Comment: make sure your most experienced people on piloting, engines and shields, this will help you survive for longer. You can also defeat intruders by opening the doors to space. Then just try and survive until they get bored of you and leave. This is why I prefer energy weapons over missile and drone weapons.

Comment: another usefull tip can be found here - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/238186/124887

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All enemies will eventually try to escape after a while, even if undamaged. This means that even if you are both unable to hurt each other, the battle will eventually end.

Once the fight is over you can put on your distress beacon and hope for rescue.

Comment: Didn't knew that, that's a useful strategy when on stress.

Comment: distress beacon? rescue? Is this just a funny phrase? Cause when ever I run out of fuel, I simply clicked "return to hangar".

Comment: really was there an update. I trained all my crew in weapons, piloting, engines and shields. The battle took hours as I let it run in the background while I got on with some work

Answer (score 1):

There's no specific tactic to recommend in your situation - as in any situation in FTL, you'll either fend off the attacker (until one of you is destroyed / able to flee) with whatever weapons / abilities you have left... or you won't, and you'll get to try again.

There are some general tactics that can help you to *avoid* getting into this situation next time:

- Consider diversifying your weapons portfolio - lasers, flak cannons and beams don't run out of ammunition.
- If using explosives, always buy at least one missile whenever you get the chance - and try to ensure that you've always got scrap to spend on them.
- Same goes for fuel - always buy it when you can. In my experience trying to maintain around 10 fuel at all times is a reasonable aim on Easy difficulty.